# Flutter Timeout waiting for the application to start

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Hello yesterday I was working on my flutter app with completely normality, but today I'm getting this error:

```
timeout waiting for the application to start
```

I dont install any new plugin. Now the app install on the device and open a white screen and close immediately.

Here is the complete log:

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
timeout waiting for the application to start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:
With the new admob release (2018-10-05), you need to put the Admob AppId in the AndroidManifest

Comment: Please share the tag here..I am facing the same issue